# Make the anchor textTabs to be a multiple line field instead of a single line

Tags: docusignapi

I'm developing against the DocuSign API, and when creating an envelope I need to place a multi line tab in the document. Also, this tab would need to be conditional to a radio group, which is not a problem, as this functionality was already achieved using the conditionalParentLabel & conditionalParentValue properties. I'm not finding a way to set this tab to be multi-line, could you please advice if this is possible or if a custom tab is needed instead?

Sending this when creating the envelope

```
"textTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "[freeText]",
    "conditionalParentLabel": "radioGroupA",
    "conditionalParentValue": "Yes",
}]
```

generates the following (it does not let you enter more characters than showed in the picture):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqqqD.png)

This is the last thing I tried, it breaks in the UI.

```
"textTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "[freeText]",
    "conditionalParentLabel": "radioGroupA",
    "conditionalParentValue": "Yes",
    "height": "1000",
    "maxLength": "20000"
}]
```

The expected value is to see a single multi-line field in the document where the string [freeText] is placed.

Answer (score 0):

[Anchor Strings](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/auto-place/) are meant to help you place signing elements (tabs) and are not supporting free text/rich-text or multi-line. You can in most cases just use part of the text to place your tab, there's no need to write the entire text that shows there, as long as DocuSign can find this text - it will place the tab.

**Edit:** You are confused about what is "anchor string" which is how DocuSign finds where to place your signing elements. You can certainly have a text tab that has multiple lines.

Comment: I am in fact able to add a free text but it's only a single line text. We need the space to write to admit multiple lines instead.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: To allow the signer to write more than 1 line if needed

Comment: this is not the anchor string, you're confused

Comment: Text tabs allow the signer to enter multiple lines, I didn't realize that's what you're asking. Not sure what is the issue.

Comment: There is some confusion, are you trying to pre-fill the text BEFORE someone signs? is that the problem here?

Comment: When adding a text tab as this:
"textTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "[freeText]",
    "conditionalParentLabel": "radioGroupA",
    "conditionalParentValue": "Yes"
}]
it only allows to enter a line of characters, not multiple lines

Comment: I'm not trying to pre-fill the text. I just need to add a multi-line field in the document using anchors (textTabs) to allow the signer to fill it out with multiple lines. Thanks for the help and patience!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what the text tab looks like? when I try I get multiple lines

Comment: I just added a screenshot and how I'm configuring the envelope in the description of the question

Comment: The height you have as a 1000, but that doesn't look like a 1000, can you make it much less? maybe 100?

Comment: Please also include a width, width and height